# HTTPS with Istio and certificate in Azure: Error reading P12 data: asn1: structure error: tags don't match

Tags: azure, kubernetes, istio

I'm trying to configure https traffic on my cluster. My certificate has been generated with "App Service Certificate" in Azure, which is connected to a keyvault.

The keyvault is mounted as a volume in the cluster with an ingress overlay. If I browse to the volume mounted by the ingress, I can see my certificate as string.

However, the istio ingress pod is unable to mount the certificate as secret. In the logs I can see the following error:

```
failed to get data in spc istio-system/istio-tls for secret ingress-cert-tls, err: failed to get cert data from file /var/lib/kubelet/pods/f4d74a73-20ee-41f0-9d4c-eaef29ace025/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/ingressgateway-certs/mount/..data/mysecret 3, err: pkcs12: error reading P12 data: asn1: structure error: tags don't match (16 vs {class:1 tag:13 length:73 isCompound:false}) {optional:false explicit:false application:false private:false defaultValue:<nil> tag:<nil> stringType:0 timeType:0 set:false omitEmpty:false} pfxPdu @2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So, after hours of try and errors, I finally figure it out. The issue is caused by `App Service Certificate` that exports the certificate in the keyvault as a `secret`, not as a `certificate`.

On github, the two teams (responsible for App Service Certificate and the CSI driver for k8s) just argue and blame each other, but nobody did anything about this for the last 2+ years.

https://github.com/Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/issues/273

The solution is to export the secret, and reimport it as a certificate in the KV. This means that you lose the feature of certificate rotation, and you need to reimport the certificate manually.

In azure, the `SecretProviderClass` needs to point to the name of the certificate that you have just imported.